# how to validate duplicate email in magento admin on edit and add in custom module

Tags: php, validation, email, magento

I need to validate duplicate email in magento on edit and add action. Basically on edit if i changed email id if that is available in database then i need to got message duplicate email.... if I add then i also want to validate duplicate email in magento.

my save function in admin

---

```
public function saveAction()
       { 
         if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
         {


           try {

                 $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                 $currentTimestamp = time();
                 $postData['updated_at']= $currentTimestamp;
                 $postData['seller_other_sale_sites'] = implode(',',$postData['seller_other_sale_sites']);
                 $sellerModel = Mage::getModel('seller/seller');
               if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0 )
                  $sellerModel->setCreatedTime(
                     Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                            ->gmtDate()
                    );
                  $sellerModel
                    ->addData($postData)
                    ->setUpdateTime(
                             Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                             ->gmtDate())
                    ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->save();
                 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                               ->addSuccess('successfully saved');
                 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                                ->settestData(false);
                 $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
          } catch (Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                                  ->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                 ->settestData($this->getRequest()
                                    ->getPost()
                );
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit',
                            array('id' => $this->getRequest()
                                                ->getParam('id')));
                return;
                }
              }
              $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
```

I need to validate that on save function

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in helper class that takes $email as parameter

```
public function customerExists($email, $websiteId = null)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($customer->getId()) {
            return $customer;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Before you perform save operation, use the helper function this way.

`Mage::helper('modulename')->customerExists($email, $websiteId);`

If a customer is already there it will return the customer object and if it doesn't, it will return false. So you can write remaining code/throw exception/ set error message accordingly.

Comment: i m not using customer model.. i need a function in core php by that i need to validate by helper

Answer (score 0):

from `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer` this code checks for unique email `_beforeSave` before save (unless updating an existing customer in which case it checks for duplicates on just that customer).

This is within the Mage system, but doesn't use any models.

```
    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $bind    = array('email' => $customer->getEmail());

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getEntityTable(), array($this->getEntityIdField()))
        ->where('email = :email');
    if ($customer->getSharingConfig()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $bind['website_id'] = (int)$customer->getWebsiteId();
        $select->where('website_id = :website_id');
    }
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $bind['entity_id'] = (int)$customer->getId();
        $select->where('entity_id != :entity_id');
    }

    $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    if ($result) {
        throw Mage::exception(
            'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This customer email already exists'),
            Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
        );
    }
```